# html table overflow-x is not working with display flex

Tags: html, html-table, flexbox

Responsive Table Overflow-x is not working inside flex-basis.

```html
<style>
   table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
   }
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     height: 100%;
     min-width: 320px;
   }
   .grid6 {
     flex-basis: 100%;
     padding: 4px;
   }
   th, td {
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>Responsive Table</h2>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="grid6">
         <div class="table__outer">
            <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
               <table>
                  <tr>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                     <th>Points</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Jill</td>
                     <td>Smith</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                     <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Eve</td>
                     <td>Jackson</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                     <td>94</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Adam</td>
                     <td>Johnson</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                     <td>67</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .grid__container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      height: 100%;
      min-width: 320px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .grid6 {
      flex-basis: 100%;
      padding: 4px;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Responsive Table</h2>
  <div class="grid__container">
    <div class="grid6">
      <div class="table__outer">
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Points</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Jill</td>
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Adam</td>
              <td>Johnson</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>67</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```